# Using mozilla firefox with utf-8 addresses (in greek) on mac

Tags: firefox, osx-lion, browsing

Very often when I use firefox (any version from 10+) and I type my utf-8 seo url it behaves strangely. For example it randomly cuts the url and adds the url again at whole like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΕΣ/ΛΑΛΑ
```

would make it as

```
http://www.mysite.com/ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙhttp://www.mysite.com/ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΕΣ/ΛΑΛΑ
```

resulting in converting the url to urlencoded letters and 404 errors.

I am using Lion with the latest firefox (yes I have uninstalled it once and reinstalled it).